# simulate background-size:cover on <video> or <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I simulate the functionality of `background-size:cover` on an html element like `<video>` or `<img>`?

I'd like it to work like

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: okay, I've never used background-size: cover; but I looked at it online, so what your wanting is a way to have a fullscreen image / video which resizes when the window resizes?

Comment: Yes, but there are subtleties with `cover`. See Background-size 101 on [link](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/03/02/using-css-background-size-responsively/).

Comment: okay so to simplify 100% width of an image / video and if there as an overflow it gets cut? If you're wanting this I can see if I can code that, but for video you should keep in mind you would need a custom player because in most browsers the controls are at the bottom of the player and they would get cut of if there is an overflow ...

Comment: Yes, overflow equally on opposite sides. I'm aware of the video controls issue.

Comment: okay, what's wrong with just using width="100%" on an image?

Comment: If the window is taller than the image it will leave empty space somewhere along the vertical axis, I think. In such a case the image should instead overflow on the sides and its height be the same as the window. And the converse should happen when the window is wider than the image.

Comment: so in simple terms if image height is less than browser height make image fit to browser so it has the height of the browser

Comment: For the record: what you're looking for is the css 'object-fit' property on a video element. It's poorly supported.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's how I did this. A working example is in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCtMm/).

```js
var min_w = 300; // minimum video width allowed
var vid_w_orig;  // original video dimensions
var vid_h_orig;

jQuery(function() { // runs after DOM has loaded

  vid_w_orig = parseInt(jQuery('video').attr('width'));
  vid_h_orig = parseInt(jQuery('video').attr('height'));
  $('#debug').append("<p>DOM loaded</p>");

  jQuery(window).resize(function () { resizeToCover(); });
  jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
});

function resizeToCover() {
  // set the video viewport to the window size
  jQuery('#video-viewport').width(jQuery(window).width());
  jQuery('#video-viewport').height(jQuery(window).height());

  // use largest scale factor of horizontal/vertical
  var scale_h = jQuery(window).width() / vid_w_orig;
  var scale_v = jQuery(window).height() / vid_h_orig;
  var scale = scale_h > scale_v ? scale_h : scale_v;

  // don't allow scaled width < minimum video width
  if (scale * vid_w_orig < min_w) {scale = min_w / vid_w_orig;};

  // now scale the video
  jQuery('video').width(scale * vid_w_orig);
  jQuery('video').height(scale * vid_h_orig);
  // and center it by scrolling the video viewport
  jQuery('#video-viewport').scrollLeft((jQuery('video').width() - jQuery(window).width()) / 2);
  jQuery('#video-viewport').scrollTop((jQuery('video').height() - jQuery(window).height()) / 2);

  // debug output
  jQuery('#debug').html("<p>win_w: " + jQuery(window).width() + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>win_h: " + jQuery(window).height() + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>viewport_w: " + jQuery('#video-viewport').width() + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>viewport_h: " + jQuery('#video-viewport').height() + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>video_w: " + jQuery('video').width() + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>video_h: " + jQuery('video').height() + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>vid_w_orig: " + vid_w_orig + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>vid_h_orig: " + vid_h_orig + "</p>");
  jQuery('#debug').append("<p>scale: " + scale + "</p>");
};
```

```css
#video-viewport {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1; /* for accessing the video by click */
}

#debug {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video-viewport">
  <video autoplay controls preload width="640" height="360">
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm"type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.ogv"type="video/webm" />
  </video>
</div>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: Why was this solution downvoted? For all intents and purposes it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found for this issue. Thanks!

Comment: This works great if the video is big and the window small, but will not work for me if the window is bigger than the video and the video needs upscaling. I added the min trick from @Timothy-Ryan-Carpenter ([answer down here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797632/simulate-background-sizecover-on-video-or-img#answer-15515336)) to the video tag as : `video { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }` and it works like a charm.

Comment: I found this approach useful as well, and packaged it as a simple jQuery plugin for any interested: https://github.com/aMoniker/jquery.videocover

Comment: Despite what @AlexandreDuBreuil says, this scales videos up just fine (see for yourself: http://fiddle.jshell.net/GCtMm/show/). This is definitely the best solution here. Shame it's so JS heavy compared to the other answer here, but that's what you need if you want `background-size: cover` for video.

Comment: @JimGreenleaf can you explain how your script is to be used?
i'm trying like this: $("#video_id").videocover(); but the result is not cover. the video fits the screen but is not cropped, leaving exposed areas of the background.

Answer (score 216):

This is something I pulled my hair out over for a while, but I came across a great solution that doesn't use any script, and can achieve a perfect cover simulation on video with 5 lines of CSS (9 if you count selectors and brackets). **This has 0 edge-cases in which it doesn't work perfectly, short of CSS3-compatibility**.

You can see an example **[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150602215021/http://www.lifesworkfilms.com/)** (archived)

The problem with [Timothy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15515336/2578509), is that it doesn't handle scaling correctly. If the surrounding element is smaller than the video file, it isn't scaled down. Even if you give the video tag a tiny initial size, like 16px by 9px, `auto` ends up forcing it to a minimum of its native file-size. With the current top-voted solution on this page, it was impossible for me to have the video file scale down resulting in a drastic zoom effect.

If the aspect ratio of your video is known, however, such as 16:9, you can do the following:

```
.parent-element-to-video {
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 177.77777778vh; /* 100 * 16 / 9 */
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 56.25vw; /* 100 * 9 / 16 */
}
```

If the video's parent element is set to cover the entire page (such as `position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100vh;`), then the video will, too.

If you want the video centered as well, you can use the surefire centering approach:

```
/* merge with above css */
.parent-element-to-video {
    position: relative; /* or absolute or fixed */
}
video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /* % of surrounding element */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* % of current element */
}
```

Of course, `vw`, `vh`, and `transform` are CSS3, so if you need [compatibility with much older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport%20units), you'll need to use script.

Comment: This is the best answer. No javascript, pure CSS, scales correctly and centered.

Comment: Ah yeah man. This here is THE answer for 2016. Ignore all others.

Comment: would you care to explain why this works ? I cant wrap my head around it. what do `vh` and `vw` have to do with anything ?

Comment: `vw` and `vh` equate to "percentage of the viewport [width/height]". It works because you're using a percentage of the width to define the height (or vice versa) which isn't possible with the `%` unit.

Comment: @insidesin: Post a fiddle?

Comment: @Qwertman Look at your example, rescale the website and look for a fine white line that goes in and out at different sizes. Firefox.

Comment: This is the correct answer by far. Amazing.

A small improvement: If using the Youtube Iframe API, use `width: calc(110vh * 16 / 9);` and `min-height: calc(110vw * 9 / 16);` to hide the youtube logo.

Comment: Needs a fiddle, isn't reproducible for me

Comment: Wow, excellent! No JavaScript, no shims - just pure and 100% valid CSS. I tested it with Firefox 43.0.1, Chrome 53, IE 11, Opera 29.0 and Safari 10.0. But I'm sure it works with much older browsers too, since it is only pure CSS 3 support.

Comment: Very nice solution! But what if I don't know the aspect ratio? Is really necessary JS for unknown aspect ratio?

Comment: The `width: auto` would make this solution bullet proof. IE9+

Comment: @M-Pixel I can't make it work, here a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jf00prjL/, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @AllanRaquin because this solution uses vh, it doesn't work with containers that are a different size from the viewport.

Comment: In 2020, the best solution is object-fit: cover, as described in the answer by Daniël de Wit

Comment: All this does is overscale the video more than it needs to be, I'm sure there's a dynamic option somewhere.

Comment: Still the best solution for embeded iframes videos. (Not the original question though)

Answer (score 173):

For some browsers you can use

```
object-fit: cover;
```

http://caniuse.com/object-fit

Comment: This is a very powerful declaration that, if browsers adopted it, would put an end to a lot of woes with scaling things on websites.

Comment: There is a polyfill for those browses that don't support it (yet): https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit

Comment: had to apply as well `height: 100%; width: 100%;`. thanks for this modern answer

Comment: I made an answer based on this one with [examples and informations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40692082/1248177). Thank you for pointing out this feature!

Comment: Good old Microsoft, holding back technology yet again. What do you supposed they do all day?

Comment: Ah, mad I read this after implementing the accepted answer haha. Ripped all of that code out and went with this (plus width/height 100%). IE11 can settle for an image background fallback.

Comment: You made my day !

Comment: This answer fits the bill in 2021.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for 2021! Thank you.

Answer (score 141):

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/cxb5oe0y/)

Using background cover is fine for images, and so is width 100%. These are not optimal for `<video>`, and these answers are overly complicated. You do not need jQuery or JavaScript to accomplish a full width video background.

Keep in mind that my code will not cover a background completely with a video like cover will, but instead it will make the video as big as it needs to be to maintain aspect ratio and still cover the whole background. Any excess video will bleed off the page edge, which sides depend on where you anchor the video.

The answer is quite simple.

Just use this HTML5 video code, or something along these lines: (test in Full Page)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; 
  height:100%; 
  overflow:hidden;
}

#vid{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1000; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<video id="vid" video autobuffer autoplay>
  <source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The min-height and min-width will allow the video to maintain the aspect ratio of the video, which is usually the aspect ratio of any normal browser at a normal resolution. Any excess video bleeds off the side of the page.

Comment: This is far simpler than the other answers, and works fine for me. Just setting `min-width` or `min-height` does the trick.

Comment: This solution doesn't center the video like cover does.

Comment: just a comment to prevent newbies from pulling their hair out: #video_background{ should be #videobackground{.

Comment: +10 for you ... i cannot upvote your answer enough ... thank you very much for posting this ... the trick that did it for me was bottom/right: 0.

Comment: What is the z-index for ?!!

Comment: The z-index moves the video to the background, placing it under any other content that might exist within the same parent tag.

Comment: This doesn't scale down a video at all (I didn't try scaling one up), which causes numerous problems if the browser window is small, and the video is large. So basically it only takes care of the bleed part of the background-size: cover, not the scaling part.

Comment: With current technologies this should be the accepted answer: a CSS solution is preferable to a Javascript one. Even though it requires you to set your parentNode properly. For centering the video, use this:
`position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`.

Comment: I just put this in, and found that with translate -50%, it was simply going off the page and was unviewable. I removed the negative signs on the translate functions and it actually seems to work pretty well.

Comment: @Sjeiti Complete agree, this is exactly what I did. Giving `position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%;` makes it behaves identically to a centered background image with background-size: cover .

Comment: Just a note to say that from what I can tell, this won't scale up a video if the user has a very large screen. I added an extra media query for that situation to just set the video width to 100%.

Comment: This solution is also very useful for <img> tags that uses srcset attribute for responsive images

Comment: This is the best and simplest answer. Some css framework will add `max-width: 100%` (like tailwindcss), so to solve it just add `max-width: none`.

Answer (score 22):

Based on [Daniel de Wit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25078803/1248177) and comments, I searched a bit more. Thanks to him for the solution.

The solution is to use `object-fit: cover;` which has a great [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) (every modern browser support it). If you really want to support IE, you can use a polyfill like [object-fit-images](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/) or [object-fit](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit).

Demos :

```css
img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.fill {
  object-fit: fill;
}
.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}
.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}
.none {
  object-fit: none;
}
.scale-down {
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<img class="fill" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
<img class="contain" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
<img class="cover" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
<img class="none" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
<img class="scale-down" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
```

and with a parent:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.fill {
  object-fit: fill;
}
.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}
.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}
.none {
  object-fit: none;
}
.scale-down {
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class="fill" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
</div><div>
<img class="contain" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
</div><div>
<img class="cover" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
</div><div>
<img class="none" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
</div><div>
<img class="scale-down" src="http://www.peppercarrot.com/data/wiki/medias/img/chara_carrot.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Best modern answer.

Comment: This is _the answer_ for anyone targeting modern browsers. Using `object-fit: cover` and `width` and `height` set to 100%, you get a proportionately-scaled `img` or `video` zoomed on center without any fuss.

Answer (score 16):

The other answers were good but they involve javascript or they doesn't center the video horizontally AND vertically.

You can use this full CSS solution to have a video that simulate the background-size: cover property:

```
  video {
    position: fixed;           // Make it full screen (fixed)
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;               // Put on background

    min-width: 100%;           // Expand video
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;               // Keep aspect ratio
    height: auto;

    top: 50%;                  // Vertical center offset
    left: 50%;                 // Horizontal center offset

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);         // Cover effect: compensate the offset

    background: url(bkg.jpg) no-repeat;      // Background placeholder, not always needed
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The video didn't scale up to fullscreen. Can I see your html for this example? Is it just a video tag in the body?

Comment: Really nice solution. It didn't work for me at first but it was probably something I missed cause when I copied and pasted your css, it worked! Thanks ;)

Comment: worked great for me. i just changed position:fixed to absolute

Answer (score 13):

[M-Pixel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997746/3735325) is great in that it solves the scaling problem of [Timothy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15515336/2578509) (the video will scale up but not down, so if your video is really large there are good chances you will only see a small zoomed in part of it). However, that solution is based on false assumptions related to the size of the video container, namely that it is necessarily 100% of the viewport's width and height. I have found a few cases where it didn't work for me, so I decided to tackle the problem myself, and I believe I came up with the **ultimate solution**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="video-container">
        <video width="1920" height="1080" preload="auto" autoplay loop>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent-container {
  /* any width or height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  /* center vertically */
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}
.video-container::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 100% * 9 / 16 */
}
.video-container video {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  /* center horizontally */
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

It is also based on the ratio of the video, so if your video has a ratio other than 16 / 9 you will want to change the padding-bottom %. Other than that, it works out of the box. Tested in IE9+, Safari 9.0.1, Chrome 46, and Firefox 41.

### EDIT (March 17, 2016)

Since I posted this answer I've written a small CSS module to simulate both `background-size: cover` and `background-size: contain` on `<video>` elements: http://codepen.io/benface/pen/NNdBMj

It supports different alignments for the video (similar to `background-position`). Also note that the `contain` implementation is not perfect. Unlike `background-size: contain`, it won't scale the video past its actual size if the container's width and height are bigger, but I think it can still be useful in some cases. I've also added special `fill-width` and `fill-height` classes that you can use together with `contain` to get a special mix of `contain` and `cover`... try it out, and feel free to improve it!

Comment: This does not scale the video above the normal resolution to make it fit 100% width/height no matter what. Thus it's not replicating 'cover' functionality.

Comment: @jetlej It does here. What browser are you testing on? Did you look at my codepen?

Comment: It worked nicely as a fallback on Edge for me. Cheers

Comment: @MrThunder what do you use as your main solution if you use this as a fallback?

Comment: @benoitr007 I used `object-fit: cover` for FF and chrome and your solution with Modernizr for IE

Answer (score 8):

`object-fit: cover` is the best answer with this IE, Safari polyfill.

https://github.com/constancecchen/object-fit-polyfill

It is supporting `img`, `video` and `picture` elements.

Answer (score 4):

CSS and little js can make the video cover the background and horizontally centered.

CSS:

```
video#bgvid {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; 
    left: 50%; 
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -1; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS: (bind this with window resize and call once seperately)

```
$('#bgvid').css({
    marginLeft : '-' + ($('#bgvid').width()/2) + 'px'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Right after our long comment section, I think this is what you're looking for, it's jQuery based:

**HTML:**

```
<img width="100%" id="img" src="http://uploads8.wikipaintings.org/images/william-adolphe-bouguereau/self-portrait-presented-to-m-sage-1886.jpg">
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
       var img = document.getElementById('img')
       if(img.clientHeight<$(window).height()){
            img.style.height=$(window).height()+"px";
       }
       if(img.clientWidth<$(window).width()){
            img.style.width=$(window).width()+"px";
       } 
}
​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

​The code above is using the browsers width and height if you where doing this within a div, you would have to change it to something like this:

**For Div:**

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width:100px; max-height: 100px;" id="div">
     <img width="100%" id="img" src="http://uploads8.wikipaintings.org/images/william-adolphe-bouguereau/self-portrait-presented-to-m-sage-1886.jpg">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
       var img = document.getElementById('img')
       if(img.clientHeight<$('#div').height()){
            img.style.height=$('#div').height()+"px";
       }
       if(img.clientWidth<$('#div').width()){
            img.style.width=$('#div').width()+"px";
       } 
}
​</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

I should also state that I've only tested this is Google Chrome... here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ADCKk/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't seem to do anything when I change the size of the Result frame, or the browser size. I tried this in Chrome.

Comment: I've updated it, but i still have a slight issue that if you decrease the width to much it suddenly jumps...
http://jsfiddle.net/ADCKk/1/

Comment: okay, sorry but I'm clueless, I've tried so many things I think i've confused myself, I'm not sure if it's possible... The script above only works when you refresh the page, to make it work when you resize a window you would need to use the window.resize event in js, but I can't get it working, maybe you can with that info :) good luck anyway

Answer (score 3):

The top answer doesn't scale down the video when you're at browser widths of less than your video's width. Try using this CSS (with #bgvid being your video's id):

```
#bgvid {
     position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Why is the negative `z-index` necessary?

Comment: It is not — just helpful when designing with multiple layered elements. I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

i'm gunna post this solution as well, since i had this problem but the other solutions did not work for my situation...

i think to properly simulate the `background-size:cover;` css property on an element instead of an elements background-image property, you'd have to compare the images aspect ratio to the current windows aspect ratio, so no matter what size (and also in case the image is taller than wider) the window is the element is filling the window (and also centering it, though i don't know if that was a requirement)....

using an image, just for simplicity's sake, i'm sure a video element would work fine too.

first get the elements aspect ratio (once it's loaded), then attach the window resize handler, trigger it once for initial sizing:

```
var img = document.getElementById( "background-picture" ),
    imgAspectRatio;

img.onload = function() {
    // get images aspect ratio
    imgAspectRatio = this.height / this.width;
    // attach resize event and fire it once
    window.onresize = resizeBackground;
    window.onresize();
}
```

then in your resize handler you should first determine whether to fill width or fill height by comparing the window's current aspect ratio to the image's original aspect ratio.

```
function resizeBackground( evt ) {

// get window size and aspect ratio
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    windowAspectRatio = windowHeight / windowWidth;

//compare window ratio to image ratio so you know which way the image should fill
if ( windowAspectRatio < imgAspectRatio ) {
    // we are fill width
    img.style.width = windowWidth + "px";
    // and applying the correct aspect to the height now
    img.style.height = (windowWidth * imgAspectRatio) + "px";
    // this can be margin if your element is not positioned relatively, absolutely or fixed
    // make sure image is always centered
    img.style.left = "0px";
    img.style.top = (windowHeight - (windowWidth * imgAspectRatio)) / 2 + "px";
} else { // same thing as above but filling height instead
    img.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
    img.style.width = (windowHeight / imgAspectRatio) + "px";
    img.style.left = (windowWidth - (windowHeight / imgAspectRatio)) / 2 + "px";
    img.style.top = "0px";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This approach just uses css and html. You can actually stack a divs below the video easily. It is cover but not centered while you resize.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "contain">
<div id="vid">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CCS:**

```
/*
filename:style.css
*/
body {
    margin:0;
}

#vid video{
position: absolute; 
right: 0; 
top: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
width: auto; 
height: auto; 
}

#contain {
width:100%;
height:100%;
zoom:1%;/*Without this the video will be stretched and skewed*/ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Hidden Hobbes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3400962/hidden-hobbes)

> This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from Hidden Hobbes ending in 6 days.
>   Inventive use of viewport units to obtain a flexible CSS only solution.

You opened a bounty on this question for a CSS only solution, so I will give it a try. My solution to a problem like this is to use a fixed ratio to decide the height and width of the video. I usually use Bootstrap, but I extracted the necessary CSS from there to make it work without. This is a code I have used earlier to among other things center an embeded video with the correct ratio. It should work for `<video>` and `<img>` elements too It's the top one that is relevant here, but I gave you the other two as well since I already had them laying around. Best of luck! :)

[jsfiddle fullscreen example](https://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/ak2q71dd/embedded/result/)

```css
.embeddedContent.centeredContent {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.embeddedContent.rightAlignedContent {
    margin: auto 0px auto auto;
}
.embeddedContent > .embeddedInnerWrapper {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 42.8571%; /* 21:9 ratio */
}
.embeddedContent > .embeddedInnerWrapper > iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.embeddedContent {
    max-width: 300px;
}
.box1text {
    background-color: red;
}
/* snippet from Bootstrap */
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Testing ratio AND left/right/center align:<br />
            <div class="box1text">
                <div class="embeddedContent centeredContent">
                    <div class="embeddedInnerWrapper">
                        <iframe allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0" height="349" scrolling="no" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/u6XAPnuFjJc?wmode=transparent&amp;jqoemcache=eE9xf" width="425"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Testing ratio AND left/right/center align:<br />
            <div class="box1text">
                <div class="embeddedContent rightAlignedContent">
                    <div class="embeddedInnerWrapper">
                        <iframe allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0" height="349" scrolling="no" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/u6XAPnuFjJc?wmode=transparent&amp;jqoemcache=eE9xf" width="425"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Testing ratio AND left/right/center align:<br />
            <div class="box1text">
                <div class="embeddedContent">
                    <div class="embeddedInnerWrapper">
                        <iframe allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" frameborder="0" height="349" scrolling="no" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/u6XAPnuFjJc?wmode=transparent&amp;jqoemcache=eE9xf" width="425"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @turbopipp although I'm afraid you've misunderstood the reason for my bounty. I've raised it so I can award it to an existing answer, it just wont allow me to do so until the bounty has been active for 24 hours. Still, +1 for your efforts the percentage padding trick is a useful way to ensure an element retains the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: Aha, well it was no hassle really, and real nice of you to give bounty to already existing answers. I guess I should read up on the bounty system. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this CSS code.

```
video {
object-fit: cover;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the comment from [weotch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59160/weotch) that [Timothy Ryan Carpenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189256/timothy-ryan-carpenter)'s answer doesn't account for `cover`'s centering of the background, I offer this quick CSS fix:

CSS:

```
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Adding these two lines will center any element. Even better, all browsers that can handle HTML5 video also support CSS3 transformations, so this will always work.

The complete CSS looks like this.

```
#video-background { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -1000; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

I'd have commented directly on Timothy's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have a better solution its short and works perfectly to me. I used it to video. And its perfectly emulates the cover option in css.

**Javascript**

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
            //use the aspect ration of your video or image instead 16/9
            if($(window).width()/$(window).height()>16/9){
                $("video").css("width","100%");
                $("video").css("height","auto");
            }
            else{
                $("video").css("width","auto");
                $("video").css("height","100%");
            }
    });
```

If you flip the if, else you will get contain.

And here is the css. (You don't need to use it if you don't want center positioning, the parent div must be "*position:relative*")

**CSS**

```
video {
position: absolute;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this and wanted to share. This works with Bootstrap 4. It works with `img` but I didn't test it with `video`. Here is the HAML and SCSS

`HAML`

```
.container
  .detail-img.d-flex.align-items-center
    %img{src: 'http://placehold.it/1000x700'}
```

`SCSS`

```
.detail-img { // simulate background: center/cover
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;

  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```css
/* simulate background: center/cover */
.center-cover { 
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.center-cover img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-cover d-flex align-items-center">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x700">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone sees this, the best answer in my opinion is to convert the video into an animated GIF. This gives you much more control and you can just treat it like an image. It's also the only way for it to work on mobile, since you can't autoplay videos. I know the question is asking to do it in an `<img>` tag, but I don't really see the downside of using a `<div>` and doing `background-size: cover`

Comment: This is a nice idea and in some cases worth a try. Only downside is that the *.gif is (in my case) larger in filesize. I converted a 2.5MB *.mpeg to a 16MB *.gif.

Comment: I agree, and often times the `.gif` is much larger in size, while also blurrier. My view has changed since I wrote this answer. It's a shame you can't combine the best of both.

Comment: I ended up with a (shortened) *.gif for mobile and a *.mp4 for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and I solved this with the following css:

```
#video-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#video{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

Comment: This will not guarantee that a video fills its parent container, for instance, a container that is 1000px wide and 1000px tall, this solution fails when the video is wider than it is tall.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

video {
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(calc((100% - 100vw) / 2 * -1)) translateY(calc((100% - 100vh) / 2 * -1));
}
```

```html
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for a centered video that takes up the entire screen:

In pure css:

```css
.parent-element-to-video {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}

video {
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

and bonus with a ready-to-go React Component:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

interface VideoBackgroundProps {
  videoPath: string;
  children?: ReactNode;
}

const VideoBackground = ({ videoPath, children }: VideoBackgroundProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '100vh',
        overflow: 'hidden',
      }}
    >
      <video
        autoPlay
        loop
        muted
        style={{
          objectFit: 'cover',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
        }}
      >
        <source src={videoPath} type='video/mp4' />
      </video>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoBackground;
```