# How to make image previews (thumbnails) using html/css

Tags: html, css, thumbnails

http://jsfiddle.net/6rwUC/3/

As you can see on the jsfiddle link, I'm trying to create one layout for image previews. I would like to have resized images keeping original ratio, just cut off what overlays the parent div. How can I do this ?

```
.image-column {
background: #cecece;
width: 100%;
height: 180px;
overflow: hidden;}

.image-column a img {
position:relative;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CSS3 is an option, you could use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) with a negative `translate` of `-50%` horizontally and vertically, while the element is positioned with `left: 50%` and `top: 50%`  as follows:

```css
.image-column a img {
    position:relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6rwUC/6/)**.

### Update

According to your update:

> I would like to have resized images keeping original ratio, just cut
>   off what overlays the parent div.

The only pure CSS solution is using the images as `background-image` for the `<a>` elements, while you're using `background-size: cover;`:

```
<div class="image-column">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

```css
.image-column a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://domain.com/path/to/image.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However, if the `height/width` ratio of the *box* is lower than the *image*, you can use the old answer including `max-width: 100%;` for the image: **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6rwUC/11/)**.

And if the `height/width` ratio of the *box* is higher than the *image*, you need to use `max-height: 100%` for the image: **[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6rwUC/12/)**.

For dynamic calculation, you'll need to use JavaScript. Here is a [similar topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797632/simulate-background-sizecover-on-video-or-img).

Comment: Thanks but that's now what I'm looking for. If you look at new example, http://jsfiddle.net/6rwUC/9/ , I've added different size 3rd image and it shows only small part of it. What I want is to show is resized images keeping original ratio, just cut off what overlays the parent div. Like these thumbnails for example: http://news.yahoo.com/

Comment: Well, you should update your question, because of: `I would like the thumbnails to show only the center of their original images`.

Comment: Sry about the confusion, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. So there is no way to use max-width:100% and max-heigh:100% together here? Some images might have smaller ratio and would need this.

Comment: @user3187469 You are welcome. If you use them both, the image will be always smaller than the box and won't cover the entire space. Say that, you need to use JavaScript to compare the ratio of the box and the image, then apply the appropriate CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/6rwUC/4/
I've simply added `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: That's not what I want though. I'd like images to fully overlay the background <div> and that the preview show center of image without resizing it (on your jsfiddle last image shows top of the image instead).