# Adding a background video with React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple landing page that contains a fullscreen background image, that will play as soon as the content loads.

Is there a way to do this using React or CSS inside of React?

I've tried using the npm module react-drive-in, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to load my React components over the video. The video keeps loading over my other components.

Comment: I have created a simple react component for this. https://github.com/samAbeywickrama/reactjs-videobg

Answer (score 32):

```
import sample from './sample.mp4';

<video className='videoTag' autoPlay loop muted>
    <source src={sample} type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Thank the note that 'autoplay' should be changed to 'autoPlay' from Mr_Antivius.
This is an alternative way to play the video in React. It works for me. Remember that the sample.mp4 file is in the same directory of the JS file.

Comment: I try a similar import and I get a squiggly red line in VS wit the error - '(TS) Cannot find module  '<sample>'.'. where 'sample' is the name of the file I am importing.

Comment: @KevinBurton it must be just that,  you have placed your file somewhere else  so it it unable to export it.

Comment: If you're using tsx you'll need to declare a type for it i.e. ```declare module '*.mp4' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}```

Answer (score 17):

Actually, I was able to get Trevor's code working just fine in my project. I did have to add a closing tag to the source element, like so.

```
<video id="background-video" loop autoPlay>
    <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Also, note that 'autoplay' should be changed to 'autoPlay' or React will throw a warning at you and not auto play the video. Outside of those two changes, copying and pasting the code should work just fine.

ES6/Babel example:

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Example extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            videoURL: 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4'
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <video id="background-video" loop autoPlay>
                <source src={this.state.videoURL} type="video/mp4" />
                <source src={this.state.videoURL} type="video/ogg" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        )
    }
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: I also want to set my background image to be a video. Except the video's mp4 and ogg files are in my directory, and I imported them. However, the video will not appear in my browser. I am following this answer exactly. Does anybody have any clue?

Comment: @McFloofenbork - If you're still having trouble, it's best to open up a new question and post your code there, as it is a bit difficult to fully understand the scope of your issue.

Answer (score 7):

I think something like this will work:

```css
#background-video{

height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
top: 0;
padding: none;
position: fixed; /* optional depending on what you want to do in your app */


}
```

```html
<video id="background-video" loop autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You may run into problems with ratios depending on the video you use or the size of the clients screen.

So you may need to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874155/video-tag-to-fill-100-div-regardless-of-ratios) post.

Also consider the size of screens today. What are you going to do if someone has a ridiculously large widescreen or something like that? The video will not be able to fit the screen unless you have video that has the same resolution.

I'm not suggesting a video is a bad idea. I simply want you to be aware of the problems!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I'm afraid this isn't rendering in my React component, just because it looks like it doesn't know what a <video> tag is. Is there a way to do this with React instead of relying on raw HTML?

Comment: LOL sorry I didn't see that you used react

Comment: I am not sure how to use react... Sorry

Comment: Yep, not React :) But this is a good answer too. Ppl just have to wrap this snippet with React Div

Answer (score 6):

**The below code also sets a poster. That is shown while the video loads or in browsers that can't play the video.**

```
  import clip from './clip.mp4'; 
  import Poster from './Poster.png';  

    <video autoPlay loop muted poster={Poster}>
            <source src={clip} type='video/mp4' />
            <source src={clip} type="video/ogg" /> 
    </video>
```

But,its a good practice to show that background video only on larger devices. Because on mobile phones background video may take up too many system resources and effects the performance.So,add a media query and set display:block for mobile devices.