# Why won't my video background appear via my component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, debugging

I'm encountering this weird behavior where my HTML video background just won't appear in my view via my `Feed component`.  I see the `<video/>` and `<source/>` tags appearing in Chrome dev tools but I'm just not seeing the background on my browser.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import React from 'react';
import './Feed.scss';

const feed = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <video autoPlay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src={"../../../background/nyc.mp4"} type="video/mp4"/>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
            </video>
        </div>
    );
};

export default feed;
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import that video in order it to be displayed.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Feed.scss';
import myVideo from "../../../background/nyc.mp4"


const feed = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <video src={myVideo} type="video/mp4" autoPlay muted loop/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default feed;
```

Tested by myself and it worked. I assume that you use create-react-app.

Comment: yes I've tried this before:  `import myVid from '../../../background/nyc.mp4';` followed by putting in the `src` tag like so:  `<source src={myVid} type="video/mp4"/>` but I get an error that says `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.`

Comment: @luvs2spuge https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230522/adding-a-background-video-with-react  take a look at this

Comment: @luvs2spuge were you able to fix  it ?