# Full Width and Height Responsive Embedded YouTube Video

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, youtube, embedding

I'm working on a project and if you scroll down to the "What is RoadAware" section you can see a YouTube video embed that looks awful! I need the video to fill the "about-left" div 100% to match the "about-right" div. I've been struggling to find an answer, any help is really appreciated!

http://road-aware.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3` to your `video-wrapper` class

This is from **bootstrap**

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It is making progress but if you check the page it isn't aligned with the "about-right" div's height

Comment: I don't think there is easy solution for that but take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451481/scale-and-reposition-iframe-like-background-size-cover