# Set a responsive video background for Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I go about setting a video to fill the whole of this jumbotron as a background and make it responsive?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/jumbotron/

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The video: http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

Comment: So where is your video?

Comment: Apologies. Here it is: http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 Any video would do to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You should try yourself and provide a `demo` of what you done so far and ask for help for problem, anyway. you should put your `video` element and set absolute position width 100% width and height.

```css
video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="jumbotron">
<video>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried one other example posted here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624496/bootstrap-video-jumbotron

But like yours, it also fills the whole screen and not just the jumbotron.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty You have to set a certain `height` and `overflow:hidden` on `jumbotron` there is no other way. See updated.